# Geoloqi Geofencing Logic Flow

Tags: mobile, appcelerator

All,

I have been looking high and low for a solution and at this point I am baffled. I am not looking for code here. I am just looking for the proper logic flow to alert users of my app that an event is taking place nearby using Geoloqi.

My platforms:
Geoloqi: Geofencing
Appcelerator Cloud Services: User, Event and Message Management
Language: javascript
Mobile: iPhone and Android

What I am trying to do:
1) I want users of my app to be able to create an event, then create a trigger based on that event.
2) I want users of my app who are near the event to be automatically alerted that the event is happening.

What I have so far:
1) Create an Appcelerator Event - Works fine
2) Create a Geoloqi Layer including the Appcelerator EventID - Works fine
3) Create a Geoloqi Trigger for the above layer - Works fine

I can see everything getting to the Geoloqi debugger. I just don't see the alert going out. I saw a post that the anonymous user needs to subscribe to the layer in order for the trigger to send to my users inside the trigger geofence. I just don't understand how to do that. I have tried several code permutations around the user/create_anon method with a key using either the anonymous username or the user access token to subscribe to the layer with no luck. I have tried using the access token returned on init as the parameter to subscribe with no luck.

I am wondering, however, if I can get the same effect by using a place instead of the layer, and avoiding the subscription issue. I somehow doubt this as the place has to reside in a default layer.

Color me confused. I already went through hell and back just getting the push certs set up for Apple, so any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 1):

Bruce,
I'd recommend hitting the geoloqi developer IRC channel.  You can get to it from one of the developer pages on their website.  The geoloqi guys are usually online and they've been very helpful to me in the past.

If you do get it working, I'd love to hear the solution/flow for it!  Hope that helps!

Tyler

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here is what I am doing. Not sure yet if it is *the* answer, but I think it will work.

1. Create a default layer with no boundaries and a key that is the same each time the app runs. This will ensure the same layer is used based on Geoloqi's anti-dupe logic.
2. Create an anon user using the logged in user's email address since I am using Appcelerator to handle the user management. If I understand this correctly, this will also ensure the same anon-user is used if the user logs in again later. The anon user is automatically subscribed to the default layer.
3. When the user wants to create an event, the app creates an event on Appcelerator, creates a layer with a radius of x, a trigger on that layer, and sends a broadcast message to all users in the default layer using the trigger centerpoint and radius to limit the message to the immediate area.
4. If the user wants to cancel the event, the app sends a broadcast message to the default
   layer in the same way the layer was created, then deletes the Appcelerator event and the layer.

I have all the code hooked in except the anonymous user. I can see the triggers being set and the messages being created on the Geoloqi Debugger, but I don't always get them. I'll be hooking in the anonymous user next week, so we shall see.